# Why exec("2*4")( for example) does nothing in python?

Tags: python

I want to implement a way to evaluate functions for my numerical analysis assignments. For that, I'm implementing a way to transform a string representing the expression of a given function into a dumb numerical value, but it seems I cannot do a simple `exec("my function")`.

```
strings.replace(parameter , numerical_value) 
return exec(strings)
```

This does nothing.

Comment: For one thing, `strings.replace` doesn't modify `strings` but instead returns a new string, one which you are discarding. For another thing, you probably want `eval` rather than `exec`

Comment: `exec` executes *statements*, which have no value. An expression statement computes the value of an expression for its side effects, not it's actual value. The primary purpose of an expression statement is to allow a function call to be a standalone statement without having to embed it in a dummy statement like `_ = print("Hello, world")`. Grammatically, it was simpler to allow *all* expressions to serve as a statement rather than cherry-pick the ones that had any useful purpose.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `eval`:

```py
eval("2*2")
4
```

The `exec()` method returns `None`, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).